# How to Automate Review Requests

Tags: workflow

My organization creates a lot of documents that vary in presentation and style. We have technical writers to revise documents in order to make them conform to our standard guidelines.

The problem is getting the technical writers access to these documents in a timely manner.

Aside from the problem of not all content being saved on SharePoint, I am looking for a simple way for users to signal that a document is ready for review. Perhaps some kind of button in the SharePoint library?

Ideally the technical writers would have a queue of notifications they could work through with fields for date submitted, which writer is working on it, and date completed.

I'd appreciate any insight or advice on how to set this up.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take a look at the Approval workflow to name one thing. You can make it trigger when people try to publish a document in certain libraries.

The workflow will then create a Task, and if configured, send an Email to selected users, asking for approval of the document.

Introduction and more information here: http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint-help/all-about-approval-workflows-HA102771433.aspx